# Excel not notifying when other users trying to edit the same file

Tags: excel

My coworkers and I have access in the same time to the Excel file. What is our scenario: When me and other coworkers working in one of the Excel files,another user also can open and make a changes on that file. Normally excel should be notifying me or my other coworkers that "File in Use" warning, but its not happening and we can't fix that who is doing what on this file. Only between 4-5 people we are getting the same issue but for other users it's working ok. What can be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

try by changing the browser file handling in central admin